# Почему для static-метода нельзя опустить имя класса?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется пример метода, сортирующего список, в рамках которого используются статические методы `sort()` и `reverseOrder()`. Они записаны со ссылкой на класс `Collections`:

```
Collections.sort(copy, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Если метод `sort()` встречается во многих классах и без уточняющей ссылки на `Collections` не обойтись, то метод `reverseOrder()` представлен лишь в одном экземпляре. Почему, в таком случае, запись:

```
Collections.sort(copy, reverseOrder());
```

будет неверна?

Благодарю.

Comment: Вы вызываете метод sort() во втором случае в каком классе?

Comment: строка `Collections.sort(copy, reverseOrder());` находится в коде какого класса? каков контехт вызова?

Comment: один момент, выложу для наглядности gh..

Comment: https://goo.gl/b0P0Mk, строка 453..

Comment: Исходный класс во втором случае тот же самый, контекст не меняется.

Comment: тот же самый что и какой?

Comment: Просто несколько не понял вопрос: мы берем исходный метод и просто убираем ссылку на Collections, не меняя остального контекста.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Данная проблема решается статическим импортированием:

`import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;`

В противном случае, необходимо при компиляции обойти все классы в classpath и проверить наличие там данной функции.

Answer (score 3):

Касательно Вашего вопроса я вижу несколько проблем, на которые компилятор может наткнуться:

- во-первых это поиск по всем классам (довольно тяжеловесная задача, учитывая сколько раз её придется выполнять),
- во-вторых это разрушение области видимости (представьте, вы объявили переменную, которая называется так же, как один из методов в каком-либо из классов, как тогда поступать компилятору?).
- Вдобавок Вы можете просто опечататься и вызывать метод класса, о котором и не подозревали...

Думаю, проблем можно придумать много, в то время когда польза минимальна (я бы даже сказал, что вреда такой фичей привнесено было бы гораздо больше).

Comment: Похоже, я разобрался. Данная проблема решается статическим импортированием: 'import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;' В любом случае, большое спасибо.

Comment: @Dmitry08 вы можете оформить своё решение как ответ на собственный вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуй стоит, да.

Comment: Вполне подходит. На enSO полным-полно таких вопросов.

Comment: @andreycha Не согласен. В правилах данного сообщество четко оговорено "Не задавайте вопросы со множеством возможных ответов или требующие одного, но очень длинного ответа". Наличие большого количества подобных вопросов на enSO нисколько не доказывает их правильность, это так же может говорить просто о слабом уровне модерации. В любом случае, не считаю доказательством фразу "другие тоже так делают".

Comment: enSO я привел в пример, поскольку на нем правила чуть более строгие, чем у нас. И уж если это там разрешено, то у нас и подавно. Что касается тематики, то ответы на подобные вопросы (если они доступны) всегда однозначные и вполне приемлемые по объему. И уж тем более полезнее ответов на вопросы в духе "У меня код не компилируется, в чем дело?". Впрочем, давайте обсудим это на мете: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3522/106